# Unable to inject HttpServletRequest via CDI

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I think I have something wrong with my run configuration or something.  When I try to do

`@Context private HttpServletRequest request;`

I get the error

```
There is more than one Bean with type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestQualifiers: [@javax.ws.rs.core.Context()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  request, Bean Owner : [xxx, Name:xxx, WebBeans Type:MANAGED, API Types:[java.lang.Object,xxx,xxx], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.inject.Named]]
found beans: 
HttpServletRequest, Name:null, WebBeans Type:THIRDPARTY, API Types:[javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Object], Qualifiers:[javax.ws.rs.core.Context,javax.enterprise.inject.Any] from jar:file:/C:/enterprise-server-dozer-1.6.5/lib/servlet-api.jar!/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.class
Bean1, Name:null, WebBeans Type:THIRDPARTY, API Types:[javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest], Qualifiers:[javax.ws.rs.core.Context] from unknown path
```

I get a similar error if i try with

```
javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
```

With the Request, the error points to finding the same bean in the same jar file.  Like the bean is created twice.  Anything obvious I could check for to resolve this?

Comment: Is this rest? and why not just use ```@Inject private HttpServletRequest```

Answer (score 1):

This bit here

```
C:/enterprise-server-dozer-1.6.5/lib/servlet-api.jar
```

looks like you've included the Servlet API JAR in your web application, which is not permitted.

The Servlet API is provided by your servlet container. Using Maven, the dependency should be declared with scope `provided`.

Having the JAR duplicated in your application may account for the duplicate bean.